# Python web scraping exchange prices

Tags: python, html, database, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want scraping the exchange prices informations from this website and after take it into a database: https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok

I wrote this code, but something wrong with it. How can i fix it, where i have to change it? 
I am working with Python 2.7.13 on Windows 7.

The code is here:

```html
import csv
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells = []
   for cell in row.findAll('td'):
       text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
   list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

print list_of_rows

outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Pénznem", "Devizanév", "Egység", "Forintban kifejezett érték"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: what is the actual problem that you face?

Comment: Is this the error you're getting? `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file scrapetest.py on line 24, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Comment: We are **not** a code writing service, a question here should have a clear question, should list what you have tried to resolve your issue, and it should include any information that may help us figure out where the issue is. You say `something wrong with it`, but you don't indicate _at all_ what is going wrong with it. We need to know what your expected results are, and what you are actually getting as a rersult. Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Add `# coding=utf-8` to the top of your code. This will help solve the SyntaxError you are receiving. Also make sure your indentation is correct!